# How to mimic OS X scrollbar behavior with custom styled scrollbars in CSS

Tags: css, scrollbar, show-hide

I want to style a scrollbar with CSS, but I also want it to behave like OS X's native scrollbar (i.e. show only when scrolling, fade away when idle).

Is there a way to do that with pure CSS?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think browsers let you have that much of control over the native UI with CSS only.

You would need to use JavaScript to manipulate scroll events. Luckily, you don't have to reinvent the wheel, consider the following plugin: http://enscrollplugin.com/

- Uses jQuery
- Control scrollbar appearance and fading with CSS

```js
$('#scrollbox3').enscroll({
    showOnHover: true,
    verticalTrackClass: 'track3',
    verticalHandleClass: 'handle3'
});
```

```css
#scrollbox3 {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 360px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
}

.track3 {
    width: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    margin-right: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: background 250ms linear;
    transition: background 250ms linear;
}

.track3:hover,
.track3.dragging {
    background: #d9d9d9; /* Browsers without rgba support */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.handle3 {
    width: 7px;
    right: 0;
    background: #999;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-transition: width 250ms;
    transition: width 250ms;
}

.track3:hover .handle3,
.track3.dragging .handle3 {
    width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://enscrollplugin.com/releases/enscroll-0.6.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="scrollbox3">
    <h1>New Scrolling Window</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a justo erat, volutpat hendrerit dolor. Sed urna nibh, dapibus at egestas non, vulputate ut quam. Morbi a erat tristique tellus varius venenatis. Aenean lacinia sem eget turpis fringilla commodo. Sed lorem nisi, viverra a interdum nec, varius eu enim. Donec ornare, nunc quis eleifend iaculis, nulla eros mollis tellus, quis faucibus risus odio non lectus. Maecenas ac velit non metus rhoncus commodo. Nunc ligula est, ultricies sed mattis sed, dapibus at arcu. Maecenas lacinia nisl ut sem bibendum ac condimentum purus facilisis. Curabitur ut nibh lobortis libero interdum vehicula vel quis nulla.</p>
    
    <p>Suspendisse et massa urna. Donec eu lorem nec felis dapibus aliquam viverra in quam. Suspendisse ultrices, nisi ac venenatis porttitor, erat turpis dapibus augue, sed rutrum nunc ante sed enim. Aliquam et tempus mi. Nullam malesuada, nunc a eleifend pretium, justo lorem tempus justo, id adipiscing dolor ipsum sed velit. Maecenas odio massa, feugiat vel sodales ut, placerat at quam. Cras viverra diam vitae diam elementum vitae aliquet erat tincidunt. Quisque fringilla neque in lacus tempor cursus. Curabitur eget nulla et nisi dignissim tempor vel non risus. Mauris ac ipsum metus, a auctor massa. Nunc eros ante, ullamcorper a mollis nec, aliquam sed est. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
</div>
```

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/jstoudt/f2Y5S/